# Having an issue importing a local image in Next.js

Tags: image, next.js

Im trying to import a local image that is saved inside the public folder in my next.js project. The endgoal is to import a local image, save that image inside of an array of objects, to finally map over the array and produce a set of cards. Ive done it this way before with React. I used SVGOMG and converted the cleanup code into jsx..

```
import Icon from "../public/assets/undraw_barbecue_3x93.svg";

const DUMMY_CHARACTERISTICS = [
  {
    id: "card1",
    image: Icon,
    title: "Insert text here",
    description: "Insert text here",
  },

const Characteristics = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {DUMMY_CHARACTERISTICS.map((item) => (
        <CharacteristicsCard
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          image={item.image}
          title={item.title}
          description={item.description}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

const CharacteristicsCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <li id={props.id}>
      <Image src={props.image} width={150} height={150} />
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
    </li>
  );
};

Error Message: Can't resolve file path to image
```

Comment: when we import an image, actually we are importing the image object which has many properties. Try logging Icon. I don't remember exactly but the image object contains the src property which has the address of the image. Instead of Icon, it should be Icon.src

Comment: Next.js only supports [statically imported images](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images) in the following formats: `.jpg`, `.png`, or `.webp`. Try using the path string instead for the SVG, i.e. `image: "/assets/undraw_barbecue_3x93.svg"`.